# mongoose objectId validation doesnt work correctly

Tags: mongoose, objectid

I tried somethin like these strings and it return **true** unexpectedly!!

- mohamma22144
- mohamma22145

is this function reliable enough?

```
mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid('mohamma22145')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`isValid()` and `isValidObjectId()` returns true even the string is not an ObjectId. According to [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/mongoose.html#mongoose_Mongoose-isValidObjectId)

> Returns true if Mongoose can cast the given value to an ObjectId, or false otherwise.

If you want to check if is a real ObjectId you can use this RegEx: `/^[a-f\d]{24}$/i`

Example here:

```js
var regex = new RegExp(/^[a-f\d]{24}$/i);
const ids = ['1', 'mohamma22145', '5a934e000102030405000000', 'FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF']
ids.forEach(id => console.log(`${id} is an ObjectId: ${regex.test(id)}`))
```

Answer (score 2):

ObjectId.isValid(id) returns true even for invalid strings with length 12.
For example :

```
String ID                |   ObjectId.isValid(id)  |    Expected Validation               
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
594ced02ed345b2b049222c5 |  true                   |  true
dania                    |  false                  |  false
toptoptoptop             |  true(but isnt)         |  false
daniandanian             |  true(but isnt)         |  false
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

To prevent such cases, another check can be added after default validator which would return true or false based on condition, (new ObjectId created from string) cast to string === string
i.e. (String)(new ObjectId(id)) === id

A function can be created as follows to check if a string is valid ObjectId or not:

```
// Requiring ObjectId from mongoose npm package
const ObjectId = require('mongoose').Types.ObjectId;
  
// Validator function
function isValidObjectId(id){
      
    if(ObjectId.isValid(id)){
        if((String)(new ObjectId(id)) === id)
            return true;        
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}
  
// Loading testcases into array
const testStrings = [ "594ced02ed345b2b049222c5","geeks",  
                      "toptoptoptop","geeksfogeeks"];
  
// Validating each test case
for(const testcase of testStrings){
  
    if(isValidObjectId(testcase))
        console.log(testcase + " is a valid MongodbID");
    else
        console.log(testcase + " is not a valid MongodbID");
  
}
```

And the result would be:

```
String ID                |   ObjectId.isValid(id)  |    Expected Validation               
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
594ced02ed345b2b049222c5 |  true                   |  true
dania                    |  false                  |  false
toptoptoptop             |  false                  |  false
daniandanian             |  false                  |  false
```